# Why cant my server and client communicate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, server

i'm running react and a express server to handle the back-end but whenever I try and make an api call to my server.js it never goes through Im running the react client on port 3001 and the server on 3002

my fetch code looks like this:

```
// CreateAccount.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function CreateAccount() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3002/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password, email }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      navigate('/my-account.js'); // redirect to My Account page
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} required />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} required />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} required />
      <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default CreateAccount;
```

and my server code looks like this:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3002;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const session = require('express-session');

// Use cors middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, world!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'altuniai',
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  port: 5432,
});



...

app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Received a POST request to /api/register with data:', req.body);
    // hash the password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

    // store the new user in the database
    const userId = await createUser(req.body.username, req.body.email, hashedPassword);
    console.log(`User created with id: ${userId}`); // log the id of the created user

    // log the user in
    req.session.userId = userId;

    // send a success response
    res.status(201).send({ userId: userId });
  } catch {
    console.error('Error while registering user: ', error); // log any errors that occur
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

...
```

and here is the full fetch error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at handleSubmit (bundle.js:473:28)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:15215:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:15259:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:15316:35)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (bundle.js:15330:29)
at executeDispatch (bundle.js:19474:7)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (bundle.js:19500:11)
at processDispatchQueue (bundle.js:19511:9)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (bundle.js:19520:7)
at bundle.js:19680:16
```

Ive tried to put more stuff in the log but it wont even call to it which is why I think its a problem with the server communicating I'm just not sure what I have done wrong

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, what specifically do you find?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Is the code which performs the AJAX request even being invoked at all?

Comment: its not showing anything on the network tab and i'll post the rest of the function I'm using to make the request

Comment: ok im getting a bundle.js:44548 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3001/ws' failed error and a Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON error how do I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like somewhere there is HTML data being parsed as JSON data.  Which specific operation is producing this JSON error?

Comment: im not sure I would assume its the post to api/register. Ill edit it to include the full fetch error.

Comment: Is the error "Unexpected token" or is it "Failed to fetch"?  The latter could be anything, such as perhaps a CORS problem.

Comment: does your API work well from postman or similar app?

Answer (score 1):

ok actually I just figured out it was an error from my database because I forgot that table isn't called passwords sorry I wasn't looking in the right place